# PDFsharp set Width and Height of Page

Tags: pdfsharp

I'm trying to set the page width and height to 4x6 in PDFsharp from C#. I'm using the following:

page.Width = "4in";
page.Height = "6in";

Still defaults a 8X11 page.

Comment: The code works on my computer. Maybe there is an error outside the code snippet shown here.

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me:

```
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

page.Width = "4in";
page.Height = "6in";
```

Using

```
pdfPage.Width = XUnit.FromInch(4);
pdfPage.Height = XUnit.FromInch(6);
```

is better because it avoids string parsing at runtime, but the string version is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to locate the answer to this here is the code to format the page to 4X6 inches:

```
                pdfPage.Width = XUnit.FromInch(4);
                pdfPage.Height = XUnit.FromInch(6);
```